# How do I know how many times to repeat a replacement when generating a grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar

My textbook discusses Context Free Grammars, and provides the following rules:

A -> 0A1

A -> B

B -> #

The resulting string is 000#111. Shouldn’t it just be 0#1? My steps:

A

0A1

0B1

0#1

I’m missing something obvious, what it is?

**How do I know how many times to repeat a replacement when generating a grammar?**

Comment: Hi. I do not understand. The grammar generates all words of the form $0^n$#$1^n$, in particular 000#111 and 0#1..
Recall that A has two options, you can take any of them any time.

Comment: You can apply grammar rules as much as you want if it is permissible.

Comment: That grammar generates all strings of the form $0^n\#1^n$ with $n\ge 1$. There isn’t a single resulting string. The derivation $A\to 0A1\to 0B1\to 0\#1$ produces $0\#1$, and the derivation $$A\to 0A1\to 00A11\to 000A111\to 000B111\to 000\#111$$ yields $000\#111$.

Comment: So my string is valid too?

Comment: @Moshe: It is indeed.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Someone should fix this textbook. And write an answer please, so I can accept it.